# How to check whether a Hashtable is null in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

Given the following Java codes:

```
Hashtable<String,Integer> hs = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
    if(hs==null){
        System.out.println("this table is blank");
    }
```

A new Hashtable is created with no  pairs. Why there is no output from the console? By the way, how to check whether a Hashtable is null?

Comment: blank and null are different.

Comment: `hs` is not a Hashtable.  `hs` is a _variable_.  `new Hashtable...():` creates a new Hashtable object in the heap, and stores a reference to the new object in `hs`.  `null` is a special value that means "does not refer to any object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hashtable` isn't `null` when it's empty; the object itself is still there.  Use the [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#isEmpty--) method instead.

```
if (hs.isEmpty()){
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please indicate how you think this post can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not null

```
Hashtable<String,Integer> hs = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
    if(hs==null){ //true if hashtable equals to null (which is not
        System.out.println("this table is blank");
    }
```

If you want to check if it is empty or not, use `hs.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

because you are creating a new hashtable before you check. You probably need to do this

```
if(hs.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("this table is blank");
}
```